# Access properties of an object via Dust.js after running JSON Parse filter

Tags: json, gateway, api-gateway, dust.js

Is there any way to access properties of an object that was transformed into JSON through the jp (JSON parse) filter of Dust.js?

```
{
    "response": {
        "services": [
            "{
                \"prop1\":\"value1\",
                \"prop2\":\"value2\",
                \"prop3\":10
            }"
        ]
    }
}
```

For example, with the input above, I intend to receive the following output:

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "value1"
    }
]
```

Note that the values inside the service array are strings, and because of that, before accessing the object's properties, I need to run JSON parse filter.

```
[
    {#response.services}
        {
            "prop1": "{.|jp}"
        }{@sep}, {/sep}
    {/response.services}
]
```

What I've developed so far is the code above, and this code is returning the following output:

```
[
    {
        "prop1": "[object Object]"
    }
]
```

In short, what I need to do is increment this {.|jp} into something where I can access the properties of the returned object, without adding new filters.

Thanks in advance to everyone who is willing to help!